# Should I use debug keystore with Google Play Game Services during development?

Tags: android, debugging, android-keystore, google-play-games

When I'm using google play game services, should I use the ID:s you get when you export a application with debug keystore and key? I want to be able to debug the game services features during development, and later on, when the game is ready for release, I will export it via my own keystore and upload it again to the developer console. Or should I just use my own keystore from the beginning, though I believe I won't be able to debug it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#c_specify_client_id_settings), and see the note:

> **Note:** When you are ready to publish your app, you must create a new client ID in the Developer Console. You must then follow these steps again with your release signing certificate. For more information about signing applications, see Signing Your Application.

This means you will then have two client IDs, both your debug deployed app and the released app will able to connect to the game server.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know 100% but if it works like Google Maps, you will have 2 keys one for debug and another for release.

Salut